# bind and unbind mouseover mouseon

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble binding mouseover mouseon events.

I can use off to unbind them

```
$('.overview li a img').off('mouseover mouseon');
```

but on does not seem to work.

```
$('.overview li a img').on('mouseover mouseon');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you binding to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `mouseon` event. There are:

- [`mousedown()`](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)
- [`mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)
- [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)
- [`mousemove()`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)
- [`mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)
- [`mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Additionally, you should use handler function to bind an event:

```
$(".overview li a img").on("mouseover", function() {
    console.log("Mouse is over");
});
```

This is a function that executes each time the event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.overview li a img').on({'mouseover mouseenter':function(event){
  alert("hello");
}},null,null);
```

or

```
$('.overview li a img').on({'mouseover':function(event){
  alert("hello")}, 
  'mouseenter':function(event){
  alert("world");
}},null,null);
```

should work, as the .on() function needs a function to bind.

Comment: upping VisioN's answer, he answered first ;)